# I asked a question (has bounty) and found the solution in another thread

Tags: discussion

I asked this question [Unable to boot to Windows 7 successfully from the first try](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895760/unable-to-boot-to-windows-7-successfully-from-the-first-try)

No one answered it, so I put a bounty (still active). I researched more and found the solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/536757/625501

I tried to mark it as duplicate but I can't since there's a bounty.

Do I leave it open and mark it once it ends? Or do I answer it and link the original thread?